# API Graph Instagram, Insights, get count likes for user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to **get the total of like for a user profile**, to do this I'm using this endpoint : [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights#lecture:~:text=GET%20/%7Big%2Duser%2Did%7D/insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user/insights#lecture:%7E:text=GET%20/%7Big%2Duser%2Did%7D/insights)

**I know this metrics is not available in the documentation** but when I **call the endpoint with a bad metric**, the reponse show metrics available and here is the response:

```
"message": "(#100) metric[0] must be one of the following values: impressions, reach, follower_count, 
email_contacts, phone_call_clicks, text_message_clicks, get_directions_clicks, website_clicks, 
profile_views, audience_gender_age, audience_locale, audience_country, audience_city, online_followers, 
accounts_engaged, total_interactions, likes, comments, shares, saved, replies, engaged_audience_demographics, 
reached_audience_demographics, follower_demographics, follows_and_unfollows, profile_links_taps"

https://graph.facebook.com/{ig-user-id}/insights?access_token={access-token}&metric=bad&period=lifetime
```

As you can see **likes** is available.
So when I call the endpoint with the metric likes, I get a new error:

```
"message": "(#100) The following metrics (likes) should be specified with parameter metric_type=total_value"

https://graph.facebook.com/{ig-user-id}/insights?access_token={access-token}&metric=likes&period=lifetime
```

Then I add the parameter metric_type with value total_value, and I get a new error:

```
"message": "(#100) Param metric_type on field insights: This param is not valid"


https://graph.facebook.com/{ig-user-id}/insights?access_token={access-token}&metric=likes&period=lifetime&metric_type=total_value
```

If someone know what i'm doing wrong, it will be a pleasure to get the solution.

Thank's for your responses !

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to get the right api call? I'm struggling too and Facebook hasn't documented it yet

Comment: @Barbi Hi, nop I didn't found the solution ='(

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the reply in any case. Maybe they're rolling out this feature and will let us know soon..... Even though FB's timing isn't so fast, usually